# PHP and titanium for desktop development

Tags: php, titanium, appcelerator

Titanium claims to support PHP, but I haven't been able to find one example or tutorial (those on their website about services don't make any sense to me). If you are aware of any working examples, tutorials or source codes, please post them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Using Titanium Desktop with PHP](http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/desktop/php)

(Also handy is the [Titanium Desktop Programming Guides](http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/desktop/guides) which covers Ruby & Python and some of the other particulars of desktop development with Titanium)

Comment: How about more detailed examples? I am also looking for one.

Comment: Titanium Desktop with PHP has been long gone. PHP Nightrain is the best solution out there. It's opensource and works on Mac, Windows and Linux! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXt8erPLf4o

Answer (score 2):

There is one..
http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2011/01/03/introduction-to-creating-desktop-applications-with-php-and-titanium/

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example: [Titanium Demo](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/build-a-titanium-mobile-pizza-ordering-app-order-completion/)

I've tried it and it works both on iOS simulator and on an iPad. However, I only got it to work once I hosted the PHP file on a server. I was unable to get it working using local host MAMP.